# VB Windows Form Application - Set Timeout on ReadXml

Tags: xml, vb.net, forms

I am trying to read the data from an XML feed into a dataset from the web using the following:

```
Dim UsersDataset As DataSet = New DataSet
UsersDataset.ReadXml("http://www.domain/file.xml")
```

However I am hitting an issue with it timing out after 100 seconds.  Does anyone know where I could increase this timeout?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution to the issue so thought I would post it here in the hope it may help someone else out.  I had to change from using the above code to using the following:

```
Dim strURL As String = "http://www.domain/file.xml"
Dim request As Net.WebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(strURL)
request.Timeout = 20 * 60 * 1000
Dim response As Net.WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Dim objReader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream())
Dim UsersDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
UsersDataSet.ReadXml(objReader)
```

This sets the timeout to 20 minutes.